# ROS Answers SE migration: parse error

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ros hydro and studying ros tutorials in wiki.ros.org. At 11th tutorial i tried to write a publisher and subscriber. At last step "catkin_make" command had an error as below:

CMake Error: Error in cmake code at
/home/meam/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt:168:
Parse error.  Expected "(", got newline with text "
".
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed

So what is the problem ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202595/parse-error/) by [zuygar](https://answers.ros.org/users/21579/zuygar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2015-02-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-02-06**:
I guess @jarvisschultz answer fixes this. In the future, if an error message lists a specific file and line, please add the contents of this file to the question (Copy and Paste + a resulting long question text is fine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is something wrong with the `CMakeLists.txt` file that is located at  `/home/meam/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt`. The error message is telling you that on line 168 you are using a CMake function incorrectly. You would get this error if, for example, the line

```
add_dependencies(listener beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp)
```

was written as

```
add_dependencies
(listener beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp)
```

It also seems like your `CMakeLists.txt` is way too long. The one the [tutorial suggests using](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/catkin_tutorials/master/create_package_pubsub/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt) is only 30 lines long. Why is yours 168 (at least)?

To fix this problem, you need to edit that file to look exactly like the one the tutorial shows. The following commands would do this for you:

```
cd /home/meam/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/
wget -N https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/catkin_tutorials/master/create_package_pubsub/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt
```

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2015-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andrea019](https://answers.ros.org/users/27520/andrea019/) on 2016-07-17**:
Hello..! Thank you.. i tried what you said but I still have the same problem. Do you know about another solution?

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2016-07-18**:
Depends on what your errors read. If your CMakeLists.txt looks exactly like the one at the link I posted, and you're still getting an error, then I'd recommend opening a new question that contains a copy of your CMakeLists.txt and the output errors that you are getting.

**Comment by [Andrea019](https://answers.ros.org/users/27520/andrea019/) on 2016-07-18**:
I solved by deleting the catkin_ws and creating a new one.. It might be radical but it worked.. Thank you anyway jarvis :)